# call c# dll inside of vc++ project or library

Tags: visual-c++, c#-3.0

could you please tell me how to call c# dll inside of vc++ project or library. here is my c# dll code which is working fine and i just want to call this dll form vc++ project, but when i call this dll from vc++ i haven't got any response.

my c# dll code is-

```
namespace MyInterop
{
[Guid("3E0E2EB2-CC13-40fb-9346-34809CB2418C")]
public interface IMyDotNetInterface
{
    void NewFile(string a, string b);
}

[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
[Guid("3A13EB34-3930-4e06-A3EB-10724CCC2F4B")]
public class MyDotNetClass:IMyDotNetInterface
{
    public MyDotNetClass ()
    {
    }

    public void NewFile(string a, string b)
    {
        string c= a + b;
        string fileName = @"D:\file.txt";

        try
        {
            // Check if file already exists. If yes, delete it. 
            if (File.Exists(fileName))
            {
                File.Delete(fileName);
            }

            // Create a new file 
            using (FileStream fs = File.Create(fileName))
            {
                // Add some text to file
                TextWriter tsw = new StreamWriter(@"D:\Hello.txt");

                //Writing text to the file.
                tsw.WriteLine(c);
                tsw.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception Ex)
        {

        }  
    }
```

and my vc++ code is-

```
BSTR param1 = L"hello";
BSTR param2 = L"World";
CoInitialize(NULL);
MyInterop::IMyDotNetInterfacePtr pDotNetCOMPtr;

HRESULT hRes = pDotNetCOMPtr.CreateInstance(MyInterop::CLSID_MyDotNetClass);

if (hRes == S_OK)
{   
    pDotNetCOMPtr->NewFile(param1,param2);

}
```

please suggest me

Comment: Remove the catch-them-all exception handler.